# Finding factors of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $p(x) = x^2 + bx + c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers. If $p(x)$ is a factor of both $x^4 + 6x^2 + 25$ and $3x^4 + 4x^2 + 28x + 5$, then find $p(1)$

Hi guys,
I have been having some trouble with this. I have tried to divide $p(x) = x^2 + bx + c$ using long division, aka brute forcing it without avail.  Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a GCD of your two quartic polynomials, by nature it will have rational coefficient, but an integral multiple will again have integer coefficients. Your $x^2 + bx + c$ must divide this GCD. To put it briefly, what is three times the first quartic minus the second quartic?

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $\;x^4+6x^2+25=(x^2+5)^2-4x^2=(x^2-2x+5)(x^2+2x+5)$.
Now the first factor divides the other polynomial. Hence
$$p(x)=x^2-2x+5$$
so that $\;p(1)=4$.

Comment: I think you saw a $-$ instead of a $+$ or viceversa, somewhere.

Comment: One of my many typos… Thank you for pointing it. I'll correct that at once.

Comment: No worries. And next time will probably be my turn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $p(x)$ divides both quartics of yours, the difference of them will still be a multiple of $p(x)$. As suggested by Will Jagy, the clever way to do it is multiplying by $3$ the first quartic, so that we get $$\begin{align}3(x^4+6x^2+25)-(3x^4+4x^2+28x+5) &=(x^2+bx+c)(3x^2+d_1 x+e_1)-(x^2+bx+c)(3x^2 + d_2 x + e_2) \\ &= (x^2+bx+c)\left( (d_1 - d_2)x + e_1 - e_2)  \right) \\ &= 14x^2-28x+70. \end{align}$$ Since there are no third degree terms in the last expression, it must be $d_1=d_2$, and the leading coefficient being $14$ tells us $e_1 - e_2=14$; so we conclude $b=-\frac{28}{14}=-2$ and $c=\frac{70}{14}=5$, and finally $p(1)=1-2+5=4$.